# Create Amplify App via REST or the AWS SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

My team and I are working on a product that will have individual deploys for each customer. For now, it relies on 3 services: PlanetScale for database, Clerk for authentication and AWS Amplify for deploying the Next.js web app. So if we have 2 customers, we should have 2 PlanetScale databases, 2 Clerk applications and 2 AWS Amplify websites deployed.

We figured spinning up all those services for each customer is a task that should be automated, so we started working on a feature that would do that when the customer subscribed to the product. We were able to easily create a PlanetScale database via their REST API and we have people looking into Clerk.

As for Amplify, I'm aware that it can be done with AWS CDK but I haven´t found a way to make it dynamic (passing different environment variables for each deploy, for instance), or even how we'd implement it within the auto deploy feature we are building, since CDK apps are separate packages. So I was wondering if there's a simpler way to do it, maybe via REST or even AWS SDK.

Other services like Vercel and Netlify make that possible via REST API calls. I know they abstract the creation of AWS resources under the hood so I thought maybe doing something like that with Amplify wouldn't seem so far-fetched.